# Xcode showing .h and .m files in red

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, github-for-mac

Xcode is showing two view controllers, the .h and .m files in red. They're part of a git repository, and I can't seem to be able to access them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It means your file physically remove from your project.

Answer (score 1):

The files that are in red, are missing from project folder, so delete that red files and again add to the project..

Answer (score 0):

Those files are missing from the project directory. You need to find then and add into project!

Answer (score 0):

Simply 'Delete reference' the red ones, and add again to the project

Answer (score 0):

Check those files in your original source.

Right click on the red file, and you will see the Show in Finder option disabled. That means your original file is deleted from the source.

Either add that file to the path or remove it's reference from your project.